# Python3.x Pandas mean and std returning NAN

Tags: python, pandas, mean

hitting this issue , which I am unable to fix , i have a large Data Frame (Sample Posted below ) , with 5 columns. I want to calculate Std and mean for each row. somehow it keep returning NaN.

```
   CellName                Apr-2018    Feb-2018    Jan-2018    Mar-2018  mean
0  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML1    9.450841   24.119474   27.091426   17.527006   NaN
1  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML2   15.917555   10.548731   11.019208   14.592388   NaN 
2  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML3   24.957360   21.122519   21.197216   24.950549   NaN
```

I have checked , all my month columns and `float64` 
`df.types` gives:

```
CellName     object
Apr-2018    float64
Feb-2018    float64
Jan-2018    float64
Mar-2018    float64
dtype: object
```

I know that I don't need to exclude cell column and i can get mean easily by using

`df['mean'] = df.mean(numeric_only =True)`

i have also tried :

`df['mean'] = df.iloc[:,1:].mean(numeric_only =True)`

but still it remains None. Same behavior for Std as well.

Any hints on on what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: What is `df_MOE` ?

Comment: Sorry , typo mistake , in my actual code its df_MOE, update the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter `axis=1` for `mean` per rows, `numeric_only` parameter seems should be omit:

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
#df['mean'] = df.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
print (df)

              CellName   Apr-2018   Feb-2018   Jan-2018   Mar-2018       mean
0  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML1   9.450841  24.119474  27.091426  17.527006  19.547187
1  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML2  15.917555  10.548731  11.019208  14.592388  13.019470
2  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML3  24.957360  21.122519  21.197216  24.950549  23.056911
```

---

```
df['std'] = df.std(axis=1)
print (df)

              CellName   Apr-2018   Feb-2018   Jan-2018   Mar-2018       std
0  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML1   9.450841  24.119474  27.091426  17.527006  7.828126
1  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML2  15.917555  10.548731  11.019208  14.592388  2.644401
2  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML3  24.957360  21.122519  21.197216  24.950549  2.190731
```

If want add both columns [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is your friend, because `mean` or `std` need count only from original numeric columns:

```
df = df.assign(std=df.std(axis=1), mean=df.mean(axis=1))
print (df)

               CellName   Apr-2018   Feb-2018   Jan-2018   Mar-2018       std  \
0  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML1   9.450841  24.119474  27.091426  17.527006  7.828126   
1  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML2  15.917555  10.548731  11.019208  14.592388  2.644401   
2  BDG652ML_KPBENDULML3  24.957360  21.122519  21.197216  24.950549  2.190731   

        mean  
0  19.547187  
1  13.019470  
2  23.056911
```